# I want Tooltip functionality in draw2d 2.3.0?

Tags: javascript, graphiti-js, draw2d-js

Please provide me tooltip functionality in 2.3.0. As Library change will effect other parts of the application. So I need to have that functionality in this library itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.graphiti.doc%2Fjavadoc%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fgraphiti%2Ftb%2FIToolBehaviorProvider.html

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/next-msg/